# Stored procedure returning value of 1 in Entity Framework, and correct value in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio, stored-procedures

In a test application using Entity Framework I'm getting a value of **1** for the return value from the below stored procedure. In SQL Server Management Studio, I return the correct value such as **33**, **45**, **etc** depending on what the identity is.

Stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_testCredentials]
    @mainPiece int,
    @textInfo varchar(25),
    @state int,
    @UserName varchar(20)
AS
    DECLARE @returnVal AS INT 

    IF (@mainPiece = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO userList (@textInfo, @state, enteredUser, lastUpdatedUser) 
        VALUES (@textInfo, @state, @UserName, @UserName)

        SET @returnVal =   @@identity  
    END

    RETURN @returnVal
```

Stored procedure call in Entity Framework C#

```
public virtual int sp_testCredentials(Nullable<int> mainPiece, string textInfo, Nullable<int> state, string UserName)
{
    var mainParameter = mainPiece.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("mainPiece ", mainPiece ) :
        new ObjectParameter("mainPiece ", typeof(int));

    var textParameter = textInfo  != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("textInfo ", textInfo ) :
        new ObjectParameter("textInfo" , typeof(string));

    var stateParameter = state.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("state", state) :
        new ObjectParameter("state", typeof(int));

    var nameParameter = UserName  != null ?
        new ObjectParameter("UserName ", UserName) :
        new ObjectParameter("UserName ", typeof(string));

    var test = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction
                       ("sp_testCredentials", mainParameter, 
                         textParameter, stateParameter, nameParameter);
    return test;
}
```

Comment: `ExecuteFunction` is not for this purpose to get output from stored procedure; use `ExecuteStoreQuery`

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 2):

Please see [MSDN definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn236955(v=vs.113).aspx) of `ExecuteFunction`

> Executes a stored procedure or function that is defined in the data
>   source and expressed in the conceptual model; **discards any results
>   returned from the function**; and returns the number of rows affected by
>   the execution.

You have to use [ExecuteStoreQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358758(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to retrieve your stored procedure output in Entity Framework.

For example,

```
context.ExecuteStoreQuery<Product>("select * from Products where pid = {0}", 1);
context.ExecuteStoreQuery<Product>("select * from Products where pid = @p0", 
                                   new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "p0", Value = 1 });
```